# How to use webcam with guvcview and vlc at same time?

Tags: vlc, webcam

I want use my webcam with both vlc and guvcview at same time. so i tried to create duplicate of /dev/video0 by using

> gst-launch -v  v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1<

but it shows some error. the log is

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Sink:v4l2sink0: Cannot identify device '/dev/video1'.
Additional debug info:
v4l2_calls.c(493): gst_v4l2_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Sink:v4l2sink0:
system error: No such file or directory
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

so how can i use with multiple applications?
any help...